# What is a recycling counting sequence?

Tags: counter, sequence-detector

Is there any difference between the name "recycling count sequence" and "count sequence"?

I have a digital system book saying that a MOD-12 counter has a recycling count sequence of 0001 through 1100. However, I think that a MOD-12 counter would count from 0000 to 1011.

Comment: I would interpret 'recycling sequence' as meaning that an increment when at its maximum value will take it back to the start value. If it was going from 0 to n then 'recyling' back to 0, I would call that a 0..n rollover counter. On the range, it is sticking to 12 values like you'd expect a modulo-12 counter to stick to, just not the 12 you'd expect. So I agree, that's unusual though maybe not improper for the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have asked the question without giving us the context.

The recycling count sequence has to do with the repeating count sequence.  A count sequence can be anything and in any order as required by the designer.  Look up Gray counter.

You are fixated on a counter counting from 0000, while the authors started the count at 0001 to take advantage of resetting the counter when QC and QD were 1, and demonstrating the difference between asychronous and sychronous loads.  They are trying to teach you something.

From [Digital Systems - Principle and Applications](https://www.academia.edu/32938079/Digital_Systems_Principles_and_Applications) (2007): Tocci, Widmer & Moss.

[image: Synchronous Counters]

Both counters reset when 1100 is reached.

But the 74ALS163 has a synchronous load, so it is a MOD-12 counter (0001 to 1100) (count cycle is reset to 1 on the next clock cycle).

While the 74ALS191 has an asychronous load, so it is a MOD-11 counter (0001 to 1011).  It does count to 1100, but because the load occurs as soon as 1100 occurs, the counter output is reset to 0001.

If \$ \overline {LOAD}\$ was not used, both counters would be MOD-16, but although both circuits look the same, they function differently.

Answer (score 0):

Any M counter that has less than 2^N(flipflop) valid states it cycles through, must have a set of 2^N - M invalid states that could possibly occur (at power on, after noise pulse etc)

A Johnson or Walking Ring counter has a count of 2*N, whilst the number of possible states is 2^N. e.g a divide by 10 has 10 desirable states, and 22 invalid ones.

The counter is reset into a valid state.

If say, a noise spike forces it into an invalid state it will proceed from that invalid state, on a different count sequence.(This new sequence might be endless too)

The feedback logic has to ensure that

- The counter normally cycles through valid states
- If it enters an invalid state, it will re-enter the valid states sequence eventually.
- It must not remain locked in an invalid sequence. (but invalid states are not prevented)

SO, I would take "recycling count sequence" to be that normal sequence which normally clocks through, and recycles endlessly. [I have however, never heard the term]

This generally is an issue for all flip-flop feedback sequencers e.g. pseudo-random binary sequences. Often those sequences used in practice, are the small subset of possible sequences, with only a very simple gate needed for feedback.

It can also be an issue for something as simple as a BCD ripple counter, without feedback. You might implement this with a 2 input AND gate to detect 1010, and force a reset. In this case 1101 could exist.

[CD4017 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf) shows this logic feeding D input of FF3. Surprisingly, web references don't mention this. Read "CMOS Cookbook, Don Lancaster" to learn about practical logic.